# Dynamic regular expression for Nesting brackets failed due to unknow bugs

Tags: regex, perl

rencently I have met a strange bug when use a dynamic regular expressions in  perl for Nesting brackets' match. The origin string is " {...test{...}...} ", I want to grep the pair brace begain with test, "test{...}". actually there are probably many pairs of brace before and end this group , I don't really know the deepth of them.

Following is my match scripts: **nesting_parser.pl**

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
my %args = @ARGV;

if(exists$args{'-help'})   {printhelp();}
unless  ($args{'-file'})   {printhelp();}
unless  ($args{'-regex'})  {printhelp();}

my $OpenParents;
my $counts;
my $NestedGuts = qr {
(?{$OpenParents = 0})
  (?>
    (?:
      [^{}]+
| \{ (?{$OpenParents++;$counts++; print "\nLeft:".$OpenParents." ;"})

| \} (?(?{$OpenParents ne 0; $counts++}) (?{$OpenParents--;print "Right: ".$OpenParents." ;"})) (?(?{$OpenParents eq 0}) (?!))
       )*
       )
}x;


my $string  = `cat $args{'-file'}`;
my $partten =      $args{'-regex'} ;

print "####################################################\n";
print "Grep [$partten\{...\}] from $args{'-file'}\n";
print "####################################################\n";


while ($string =~ /($partten$NestedGuts)/xmgs){
 print $1."}\n";
  print $2."####\n";
}
print "Regex has seen $counts brackts\n";
sub printhelp{
print "Usage:\n";
print "\t./nesting_parser.pl -file [file] -regex '[regex expression]'\n";
print "\t[file]   : file path\n";
print "\t[regex]  : regex string\n";
exit;
}
```

Actually my regex is:

```
our $OpenParents;
our $NestedGuts = qr {
(?{$OpenParents = 0})
(?>
(?:
[^{}]+
| \{ (?{$OpenParents++;})
| \} (?(?{$OpenParents ne 0}) (?{$OpenParents--})) (?(?{$OpenParents eq 0} (?!))
)*
)
}x;
```

I have add brace counts in  **nesting_parser.pl**

I also write a string generator for debug: **gen_nesting.pl**

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
my $buffer = "{{{test{";

unless ($ARGV[0]) {print "Please specify the nest pair number!\n"; exit}

for (1..$ARGV[0]){
    $buffer.= "\n\{\{\{\{$_\}\}\}\}";
   #$buffer.= "\n\{\{\{\{\{\{\{\{\{$_\}\}\}\}\}\}\}\}\}";
 }
$buffer .= "\n\}}}}";

open TEXT, ">log_$ARGV[0]";
print TEXT $buffer;
close TEXT;
```

You can generate a test file by

```
./gen_nesting.pl 1000
```

It will create a log file named log_1000, which include 1000 lines brace pairs

Now we test our match scripts:

```
./nesting_parser.pl -file log_1000 -regex "test" > debug_1000
```

debug_1000 looks like a great perfect result, matched successfully! But when I gen a 4000 lines test log file and match it again, it seem crashed:

```
./gen_nesting.pl 4000
./nesting_parser.pl -file log_4000 -regex "test" > debug_4000
```

The end of debug_4000 shows

```
{{{{3277}
####
Regex has seen 26213 brackts
```

I don't know what's wrong with the regex expresions, mostly it works well for paired brackets, untill recently I found it crashed when I try to match a text file more than 600,000 lines.

I'm really confused by this problems, 
I really hope to solve this problem.

thank you all!

Comment: Consider also [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) for parsing balanced nested brackets.

Comment: This code seems hard to maintain. If I were you, I wouldn't build such complicated regular expressions; I'd perform the matching in several stages instead.

Comment: I want match  "$headname {}"  from a string like "A{  ... B {... $headname{}...}  ... C { ...$headname {} }}", so I write this regex expression by  $string =~ /($partten$NestedGuts)/xmgs,  $partten is the group head name partten, and $NestedGuts is the pair brackts, i think it is very effective and useful, untill encount this problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for matching nested brackets I normally use `Regexp::Common`.

Next, I'm guessing that your problem is that Perl's regular expression engine breaks after matching 32767 groups.  You can verify this by turning on warnings and looking for a message like `Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded`.

If so, you can rewrite your code using `/g` and `\G` and `pos`. The idea being that you match the brackets in a loop like this untested code:

```
my $start = pos($string);
my $open_brackets = 0;
my $failed;
while (0 < $open_brackets or $start == pos($string)) {
    if ($string =~ m/\G[^{}]*(\{|\})/g) {
        if ($1 eq '{') {
            $open_brackets++;
        }
        else {
            $open_brackets--;
        }
    }
    else {
        $failed = 1;
        break; # WE FAILED TO MATCH
    }
}
if (not $failed and 0 == $open_brackets) {
    my $matched = substr($string, $start, pos($string));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works perfectly! I turned on warnings, but it didn't print any message. However, i should learn to use Regexp::Common